# How to get all variables including constants

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have been trying to find a way to find all constants in javascript.
I have found I can get all global variables with

```js
for (let i in window) {
  console.log(i);
};
```

I do not get constants in that method.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? What possible use-case is there for this?

Comment: @3limin4t0r  Well it does nowadays, -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const   But I'm not sure this is what the OP means by constants.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What problem are you trying to solve by getting all variables?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because constants aren't enumerable.

You can iterate over `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)` to get also the not-enumerable properties:

```js
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).forEach(key => {
  console.log(`key: ${key}. value: ${window[key]}`);
})
```

Comment: This gives me more results, but `const test = 0; console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).test);` gives me undefined.

Comment: @JaimeArgila the result is an array, so you have to use the loop in the answer and check for when `key === 'test'`

Comment: I just ran `const test = 0; for(var i in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)) {if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)[i] == "test")console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)[i])}` and it still gave me undefined instead of the expected `"test"`

Comment: If you already know the variable name, then you can just use `window.test` or `window["test"]`. Otherwise, inside the for loop you have just to check `if (window[i] === 'test')`

Comment: The console gave me `undefined` when I ran `const test = 0; console.log(window["test"])`